# ModelSim Error Loading Design

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm designing a Master-Slave D Flip Flop implementation in ModelSim. After compiling (`Compile > Compile All`), I'm typing `vsim` into the console, and the only error thrown is

```
# vsim
# Start time: [time]
# Error loading design
```

Is there any way of having `vsim` be more verbose with what is going wrong? Or, alternately, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

For reference, my code is below:

**methods.v**

```
module dFlipFlop(
    D,
    Clk,
    En,
    Q
);

input D, Clk, En;
output Q;
reg Q;

always @ (posedge Clk)
if(~En) begin
    Q <= 1'b0;
end else begin
    Q <= D;
end

endmodule

module masterSlaveDFF(
    D,
    Clk,
    En,
    Q
);

input D, Clk, En;
output Q;

wire Y, inClk;

assign inClk = ~Clk;

dFlipFlop first (.D(D), .Clk(Clk), .En(En), .Q(Y));
dFlipFlop second (.D(Y), .Clk(inClk), .En(En), .Q(Q));

endmodule
```

**dflipflop.v** (My Testbench)

```
`include "methods.v"

module masterSlaveTest();

reg D, Clk, En, Q;

initial begin
    $monitor(D, Clk, En, Q);

    D = 1;
    Clk = 1;
    En = 0;

    #5 $finish;
end

always begin
    #5 Clk = ~Clk;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried specifically invoking my Test Bench file too, to no avail.

Comment: Ahh. I figured it out. It wasn't my code or the configuration, though those were good suggestions for sure. It was the student license. I'm gonna resolve it myself ha.

Answer (score 1):

If your code compiles, and directly invoking a test bench doesn't work, aka via something like

`vsim -novopt [your testbench module name here]`

or just

`vsim`

Then, at least in my case, it was a problem of licensing. Note that I am using the Student Edition of ModelSim. When I first ran `vsim` it gave a long error message explaining that I needed to put the License file (which you get during the installation) in a certain directory.

For the Student Edition, you must rename the file `student_license.dat` to `license.dat` and place it in `C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\win32pe_edu\`. Your directory structure may vary, but as I understand the naming conventions are similar.

In some cases I also read that the `license.dat` needs to be in the parent file of `win32pe_edu`, but in my case, it worked in `win32pe_edu`.

Answer (score 1):

To the Windows users:

If your code is correct and you already copied your license file (student_license.dat) in the correct folder (C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_[VersionNo]) and it still does not work try to run ModelSim as administrator. This might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by right clicking on the specific library and clicking "refresh". Then, I recompiled and restarted simulation, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was with optimization, when i started simulation with optimization ON, it didnt show created instances in testbench, and by turning it off i get the "Error Loading Design" error.
How i fix it:
in gui:
simulate > start simulation > optimization option > in the visibility tab> check the "apply full visibility to all modules(full debug mode)" .
in terminal:
vsim -gui -vopt -voptargs=+acc work.Adder_TB
(Adder_TB is my testbench module name) .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . This is how I fixed it. When I installed modelsim, in the end it directs me to a license key page! I filled it but did not receive an email!

So if you don't receive a mail containing the license key from modelsim then you will have to re-run the installation all over again! So once you receive the license_file.dat, paste it in the modelsim folder, then you will not face any such problems!